# TypeError: prevState.blockHash is not iterable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, solidity

I was trying to update the objects stored in an array. but getting TypeError: prevState.blockHash is not iterable.
here is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    dir:"",
    account: '',
    name: [],
    fido: [{
      logIndex: [],
      transactionIndex: [],
      transactionHash: [],
      blockHash: []
    }],
    loading: true
  }
```

I am setting state in this manner-

```
showusingBot= () => {
  this.setState(this.initialState)
  this.state.instance.events.Artworkcreated({
    filter: { purchased: false},
    fromBlock: 0
  }).on('data', event => {
    this.setState(prevState =>({
      fido:[...prevState.fido.map({blockHash: [
        ...prevState.blockHash,   
        event.blockHash        
      ]} )]}));
    })
  }
```

my ABI  response on console is a follows.

```
{logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x94f6d8671988ceb8ef1da862257637a198f4afefc3aef6cf3eb992dfcafb0eb1", blockHash: "0xd26937f8535a335663c9af57335f7cc783aba0e9e376408cbb92c1b3f1b28166", blockNumber: 20, …}
logIndex: 0
transactionIndex: 0
transactionHash: "0x94f6d8671988ceb8ef1da862257637a198f4afefc3aef6cf3eb992dfcafb0eb1"
blockHash: "0xd26937f8535a335663c9af57335f7cc783aba0e9e376408cbb92c1b3f1b28166"
blockNumber: 20
address: "0x20B40e09b75a21E0B857F695dE5De92a5A5b5AD0"
type: "mined"
id: "log_0d967aac"
returnValues: Result
0: "1"
1: "bhavin"
2: "masterpiece"
3: "1000000000000000000"
4: "100"
5: "200"
6: "blah blah blah!!"
7: "0x04f78093E2a1C07BF6c4527Aaa00807d3132A1Df"
8: false
id: "1"
Artistname: "bhavin"
Artname: "masterpiece"
price: "1000000000000000000"
width: "100"
height: "200"
Description: "blah blah blah!!"
owner: "0x04f78093E2a1C07BF6c4527Aaa00807d3132A1Df"
purchased: false
__proto__: Object
event: "Artworkcreated"
signature: "0xf912339172a3b7eda9cb10ecdef181d10a74fc4411fe5d7e62f550ef3698d845"
raw: {data: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…16820626c6168212100000000000000000000000000000000", topics: Array(4)}
__proto__: Object
```

I need to push a string to the array blockHash.

Comment: What does `this.setState(this.initialState)` do to your state shape?

Comment: ```componentWillMount() {
    this.initialState = this.state
}``` is as a reset to clear the stored value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole fido map callback is incorrect, it's supposed to take a function, you are passing an object.

```
this.setState(prevState =>({
  fido:[...prevState.fido.map({blockHash: [
    ...prevState.blockHash,   
    event.blockHash        
  ]} )]}));
})
```

Correct syntax is `map((current, index, originalArray) => {...})`.

But I don't think you need to map anything, I think you just need to spread the previous state's fido array and add the new element

```
this.setState(prevState =>({
  fido:[...prevState.fido, event.blockHash]
}));
```

**Edit 1**

Since `fido` is static, as you say, I suggest to instead just store its properties in an object, like you do with it currently as an element in an array.

```
this.state = {
  dir:"",
  account: '',
  name: [],
  fido: {
    logIndex: [],
    transactionIndex: [],
    transactionHash: [],
    blockHash: []
  },
  loading: true
}
```

Now, when updating the fido state, spread in the previous state **and** the `blockHash` array with new element

```
this.setState(prevState =>({
  fido: {
    ...prevState.fido,
    blockHash: [...prevState.fido.blockHash, event.blockHash]
  },
}));
```

OFC, if you wanted/needed to keep it as-is, you need to access the element correctly

```
this.setState(prevState =>({
  fido: [{
    ...prevState.fido[0],
    blockHash: [...prevState.fido[0].blockHash, event.blockHash]
  }],
}));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as it supposed to. I am trying to push a string to the array blockHash from the ABI.

Comment: @DaveBhavin I see, I think I may know but have another question. `fido` is an array, do new elements get added to *it*?

Comment: no fido is static, no elements are added but in fido, (i.e array blockHash)  arrays are updated with new elements from the ABI response.

Answer (score 0):

`blockHash` does not exist in state, it only exists in in the objects of `state.fido`. In your `setState` you need to access `blockHash` from each element of `fido` instead accessing it from the overall state.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this might be the case. Can you please elaborate, as I am still stuck with this any link related to solving this, will be appreciated.